# Quartz - Allow concurrent execution

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is it possible to trigger a Job instance on two (or more) nodes in an environment using Clustering with JDBC-JobStore?

For most usecases we trigger one Job instance on one node. In this particular case I want to have a Job triggered on ***all nodes*** at the ***same time***. Each instance of the Job handles a chunk of a large dataset, and I want the Jobs to run in parallel.

Environment:
Java/Jetty/Docker/Rancher.
Using quartz-config.xml

Comment: Why don't you use ScheduledExecutorService [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html]

Answer (score 0):

When I want to trigger a Job on only one node I use `Quartz`, and when I want to trigger a job on all nodes I use `EJBTimer`. (but I don't know if you are using EJB in your project).

Comment: Or you can use spring  @Scheduled(expression)